# AWS Lex: sending a response from lambda function with python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am having trouble with sending a JSON response from my python3.8 lambda function (default lambda_handler function). I am pretty sure I understand what I am doing after reading most of the docs and the [Lambda Function Input Event and Response Format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html#lambda-response-dialogAction). from that resource, it says the only required section is the 'dialogAction' section.

Right now, my lex-bot has 1 intent and one slot. I know that this works because when I add a logger to the code, I can see that my lambda function is recieving confirmed JSON format.

My code tries to send a final response from the lambda function, but when I run the lex-bot in the console I get the following error:

```
Invalid Lambda Response: Received invalid response from Lambda: Can not construct instance of IntentResponse, problem: The validated object is null at [Source: {"dialogAction": {"type": "Close", "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled", "message": {"contentType": "PlainText", "content": "milk"}}}; line: 1, column: 128]
```

Here is my python code:

```
import json
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # print
    
    item = event["sessionState"]["intent"]["slots"]["MilkProduct"]["value"]["resolvedValues"][0]
    logger.debug(item)
    
    return{
            "dialogAction": {
                "type": "Close",
                "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled",
                "message": {
                    "contentType": "PlainText",
                    "content": item
                }
            }
        }
```

I do not think this is necessary for you to see, but here is what the lex-bot is sending me after it confirms the slot for the intent has been confirmed:

```
{
    "sessionId": "120304235774457",
    "inputTranscript": "I want to buy milk",
    "interpretations": [
        {
            "intent": {
                "slots": {
                    "MilkProduct": {
                        "shape": "Scalar",
                        "value": {
                            "originalValue": "milk",
                            "resolvedValues": [
                                "milk"
                            ],
                            "interpretedValue": "milk"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "confirmationState": "None",
                "name": "BuyCream",
                "state": "ReadyForFulfillment"
            },
            "nluConfidence": 1
        },
        {
            "intent": {
                "slots": {},
                "confirmationState": "None",
                "name": "FallbackIntent",
                "state": "ReadyForFulfillment"
            }
        }
    ],
    "responseContentType": "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
    "invocationSource": "FulfillmentCodeHook",
    "messageVersion": "1.0",
    "sessionState": {
        "intent": {
            "slots": {
                "MilkProduct": {
                    "shape": "Scalar",
                    "value": {
                        "originalValue": "milk",
                        "resolvedValues": [
                            "milk"
                        ],
                        "interpretedValue": "milk"
                    }
                }
            },
            "confirmationState": "None",
            "name": "BuyCream",
            "state": "ReadyForFulfillment"
        },
        "originatingRequestId": "417dff57-5260-45cc-81a7-06df13fbee9a"
    },
    "inputMode": "Text",
    "bot": {
        "aliasId": "TSTALIASID",
        "aliasName": "TestBotAlias",
        "name": "Shopping",
        "version": "DRAFT",
        "localeId": "en_US",
        "id": "JTGNDOEVQG"
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I have been at this for hours and I seriously do not know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Seemingly python code is fine. Is `item` getting value properly? Input event format should be like this. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html#using-lambda-input-event-format

Comment: Agree with @shimo that the python code works fine. Perhaps print out the final response before returning it from the method. It's possible that there's no value for `item` hence the error.

Comment: @jellycsc I am getting the value of item perfectly fine. I took the data passed to the lambda function and used it as a template to index the JSON from Amazon Lex-bot.  I have tested the response in the lambda function as well and the return object looks fine (from what the docs requested). I am just not sure if I am doing something wrong in the config of the lex-bot in the console UI.

Comment: I notice this is a few months old, but if you are using Amazon Lex V2 the input event format and response formats have changed, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/lambda.html